# MiniProfiler MvcSiteMapProvider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-mini-profiler

**History**

We are getting excessive load times of over 6 seconds, on static content pages, which seems to happen around the "Render: Index", We have managed to work out its the MvcSiteMapProvider

```
*Executing Controller: Eclipse.Wi.Areas.Workin...    2.1     6314.6 +3.9    
   Find: Index   0.0     0.0    +6.0    
   Render : Index    6306.4  6312.5 +6.0*
```

We are using StackExchange MVC profiler and MvcSiteMapProvider (links below)

http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcSiteMapProvider

http://nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/

**Question**

How do we use Profiler to Profile the MvcSiteMapProvider, so we can evaluate why the load times are so excessive when using 3 menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mini-profiler is a fairly simple (but effective) profiler; it does not include hooks to drill invasively into external code. I expect to use mini-profiler for that you'd need to do a custom build [from source](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider), adding explicit profiling steps. That probably isn't overly taxing, but there are other tools that *are* designed for invasive profiling that might be more convenient (but with more impact to overall performance).